# how to make darkmode persistent in a webpage?

Tags: javascript, darkmode

I have tried the persistence through local storage, but when try it it is showing an ugly user experience because JavaScript file is loaded each single time and the code is executed each single time, the feature is ugly with local storage, how can I make some persistent local storage doesn't refresh and update the screen each time a page is loaded.

```
let dark=document.querySelector('.dark-btn');
let body=document.body

dark.addEventListener('click',function(e){
console.log('rahul')
e.preventDefault()
console.log(e)
body.classList.toggle('dark')

e.target.textContent=="dark"?e.target.textContent="light":e.target.textContent="dark";

if(body.classList.contains('dark')){
    localStorage.setItem('darkMode','enabled');
}else{
    localStorage.setItem('darkMode','disabled');
}

})
if(localStorage.getItem('darkMode')=='enabled'){
body.classList.toggle('dark')
// e.target.textContent=="dark"?e.target.textContent="light":e.target.textContent="dark";
dark.textContent="light"
}else{
dark.textContent="dark"
}
```

this is my darkmode code,but i hate this.

you can check the website I made, this has an effect like going from dark to white and vice versa when switching pages.
[darkmode link](https://rahul007cdr.github.io/persistent-darkmode/page-1.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could load a synchronous script at the beginning, after your CSS file. that checks the local storage, and sets CSS variables. The way this works, is that script pauses the loading of the page, to wait for it to download.

All your components, can then use these CSS variables to determine your color scheme.

If you want to check the color scheme the user prefers natively, you can use the `prefers-color-scheme` CSS Media Query to do that.

I know synchronous loading isn't good, but if it's a small script, I think it's fine.

Here a working link is: https://persistentdarkmode.infiniti20.repl.co/index.html

Comment: ya it worked thanks man,but is there any other way to modify the script,i dont want any script in defined in my html page.

Comment: Why's that? Script tags are fine. The approach won't work without a script tag.

Comment: Could you mark this as accepted? By clicking the green checkmark. This means that my answer worked, and was able to be understood.

Answer (score -1):

That flash is just the fallback blank screen displayed by the browser when loading the resources of the target page.

Try to go with a single page approach. You won't see similar flashing in that's